# Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a category, then $\mathcal{P}_\mathbf{A} (\mathrm{dom}(f))\implies\mathcal{Q}_\mathbf{A}(f)$

Tags: category-theory

This is a very trivial question in category theory, and the textbook I'm working from has this as a supposedly trivial example of the dual property for categories, and unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to prove it.

Definitions:

$\forall\,\mathbf{A}$-objects $X$, $\mathcal{P}_\mathbf{A} (X)$ is the property that $\forall\, A\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{A}),\,\exists!\, A\xrightarrow{f}X$.

$\forall\, A\xrightarrow{f}B$ in $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathcal{Q}_\mathbf{A} (f)$ is the property that $\exists\, B\xrightarrow{g}A$ s.t. $(A\xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{g}A) = (A\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}}A)$.

We define $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{R}_\mathbf{A}$ to be the property that $\forall$ $\mathbf{A}$-morphisms $A\xrightarrow{f}B$, $\mathcal{P}_\mathbf{A} (\mathrm{dom}(f))\implies\mathcal{Q}_\mathbf{A}(f)$.

I wish to show that $\mathcal{R}_\mathbf{A}$ holds for all categories $\mathbf{A}$, and therefore, that the dual property, $\mathcal{R}_\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{op}$ holds for all categories $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: It's any arbitrary category. The textbook I'm using states that "One can easily show that $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})$ holds for all categories $\mathbf{A}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $\mathcal{R}$, suppose $f:A\to B$ is a morphism such that $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is true.  You want to prove that there exists a morphism $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_A$.  To prove this, note that by $\mathcal{P}(A)$, there does exist a morphism $g:B\to A$.  Furthermore, the composition $g\circ f$ and $\mathrm{id}_A$ are both morphisms $A\to A$.  But by $\mathcal{P}(A)$, there is exactly one morphism $A\to A$.  Thus $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_A$.